# Service for Lock screen before opening app

Tags: java, android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to make an app in which there is a lock / password screen before you open selected apps to protect your apps.

There are some on the market such as:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en

Here is an open source one on GitHub. https://github.com/twinone/AppLocker

I realized that even if the above apps are killed, or ram the is cleared, or the phone is restarted etc. The lock screen stills shows up for the selected application.

Essentially I want to achieve the same thing that they did, but currently I am not achieving this currently with the service class I have written. I can lock the app, but when the app is killed I cannot. I have spent a great deal of time learning pending intents, alarm managers, broadcast receivers, and even studying example source code

https://github.com/twinone/AppLocker/blob/master/src/com/twinone/locker/lock/AppLockService.java

but I am not successful in my implementation.

Here is my service class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class HeartBeat extends Service {



    private static final String TAG = HeartBeat.class.getSimpleName();
    public Timer TIMER;



    private static Set<AccessGranted> mAccessGrantedList = new HashSet<AccessGranted>();
    private Set<String> mLockedApps = new HashSet<String>();
    private long lastModified = 0;
    private BroadcastReceiver mScreenStateReceiver;
    private BroadcastReceiver mAccessGrantedReceiver;
    private File mLockedAppsFile;
    ArrayList<String> packagezList;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    Map<String, ?> allEntries;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefsapp;

    String prefix;





    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        startService(new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class));












        // Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " +
        // intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        if (TIMER == null) {

            TIMER = new Timer(true);
            TIMER.scheduleAtFixedRate(new LockAppsTimerTask(), 1000, 250);

            mScreenStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                private boolean screenOff;

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



                    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                        screenOff = true;
                    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                        screenOff = false;
                    }

                    if (screenOff) {
                        //Log.i(TAG, "Cancel Timer");
                        TIMER.cancel();
                    } else {
                       // Log.i(TAG, "Restart Timer");
                        TIMER = new Timer(true);
                        TIMER.scheduleAtFixedRate(new LockAppsTimerTask(), 1000, 250);
                    }
                }
            };

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            registerReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver, filter);

            mAccessGrantedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    String packageName = intent.getStringExtra("packageName");
                    if (action.equals(Constants.ACTION_GRANT_ACCESS) && packageName != null) {
                        AccessGranted ag = new AccessGranted(packageName);
                        mAccessGrantedList.remove(ag);
                        mAccessGrantedList.add(ag);
                    }
                }
            };

            IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION_GRANT_ACCESS);
            registerReceiver(mAccessGrantedReceiver, filter2);
        }
        // this.stopSelf();



        //startforeground goes here



        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        startService(new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class));
    }




    private class LockAppsTimerTask extends TimerTask {




        @Override
        public void run() {


            sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPrefsapp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("appdb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            allEntries= null;
             allEntries = sharedPrefsapp.getAll();

            //prefix = "m";
            packagezList= null;


            packagezList = new ArrayList<String>();




            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
                    //Log.e("right key: ", entry.getKey() + "right value: " + entry.getValue().toString()  );
                    packagezList.add(entry.getKey());





            }


/*        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet())
        {
            //Check if the package name starts with the prefix.
            if (entry.getKey().startsWith(prefix)) {
                //Add JUST the package name (trim off the prefix).
                packagezList.add(entry.getKey().substring(prefix.length()));
            packagezList.add(entry.getKey());

            }
        }*/

            for(Object object: packagezList){
                Log.e("YO!", (String) object);
            }








            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            try {
                //List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(1, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
                ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager
                        .getRunningTasks(1);
                ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
                String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getPackageName();

                // Log.e("activity on Top", "" + activityOnTop);
                //   Log.e(" My package name", "" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());








                //for (Object data : newArrayList) {

                for(Object object: packagezList){

// Provide the packagename(s) of apps here, you want to show password activity
                    if ((activityOnTop.contains((CharSequence) object)) &&
                            (!activityOnTop.contains(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                            ))) {  // you have to make this check even better


                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockScreenActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        i.putExtra( "", "");
                        startActivity(i);
                    }

                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
               // Log.e("Foreground App", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Here is my LockScreen activity class (the screen that is displayed when the selected app is open) :

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class LockScreenActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = LockScreenActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Map<String, ?> allEntries;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefsapp;
    ArrayList<String> packagezList;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {



        // Grab a list of all running processes and their PIDs.
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

        // Now loop through the list of PIDs and find Instagram's PID.
        sharedPrefsapp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("appdb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        allEntries= null;
        allEntries = sharedPrefsapp.getAll();

        //prefix = "m";
        packagezList= null;


        packagezList = new ArrayList<String>();




        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
            //Log.e("right key: ", entry.getKey() + "right value: " + entry.getValue().toString()  );
            packagezList.add(entry.getKey());
        }


        // Killing any process for blocked applications when the back button is pressed while the lock screen is displayed

        for(Object object: packagezList){
            am.killBackgroundProcesses((String) object);
            Log.d("Killed Background Process!: ", (String) object);


        }



        // Now that we've got the PID, kill the Instagram process.


        // Now that we've got the PID, kill the Instagram process.

        ActivityManager  am1 = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


        // Display confirmation here, finish() activity.
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);


        startService(new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class));


  /*      Intent iHeartBeatService = new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class);
        PendingIntent piHeartBeatService = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, iHeartBeatService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(piHeartBeatService);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 300000, piHeartBeatService);*/

        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Right now I am able to lock the apps, but when the app is killed or phone is restarted I cannot. The app lock apps on the Google Play Store can successfully still lock apps with a pin when all apps are force stopped or when the phone is restarted, ram cleared, etc.

How can I achieve this like those have?

Comment: for start your service after reboot write permission in manifest file for reboot and register reciever and then inside broadcast reciever start your service

Comment: Hey Rohit, do you get solution?

Comment: HI can you share AccessGranted class

Comment: https://github.com/rrtigga/GetDisciplined

Answer (score 2):

I think u should try this ...

```
     package com.ankit.vkapplock;

 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class StartupServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){

        context.startService(new Intent(context, HeartBeat.class  ));

}
```

Dont forget to add permisson for boot_completion action.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```